# Error passing optional argument in GraphQL-Spring Boot query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

I'm trying to pass two arguments in a query:

```
@QueryMapping
public List<Customer> getCustomers (@Argument OptionalInt start,
                                    @Argument OptionalInt end
                                    ) {
    List<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();
    if (start != null && end != null) {
        try {
            return customers.subList(start.getAsInt(), end.getAsInt());
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }

    return customers;
}
```

But this error is thrown:

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.graphql.data.GraphQlArgumentBinder$ArgumentsBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'optionalInt' on field '$': rejected value [0]; codes [typeMismatch.optionalInt,typeMismatch]; arguments []; default message [Failed to convert argument value]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.GraphQlArgumentBinder.bind(GraphQlArgumentBinder.java:151) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.ArgumentMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ArgumentMethodArgumentResolver.java:71) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:81) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.DataFetcherHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(DataFetcherHandlerMethod.java:177) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.DataFetcherHandlerMethod.invoke(DataFetcherHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.DataFetcherHandlerMethod.invoke(DataFetcherHandlerMethod.java:107) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.AnnotatedControllerConfigurer$SchemaMappingDataFetcher.get(AnnotatedControllerConfigurer.java:680) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.graphql.execution.ContextDataFetcherDecorator.lambda$get$0(ContextDataFetcherDecorator.java:88) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at io.micrometer.context.ContextSnapshot.lambda$wrap$1(ContextSnapshot.java:92) ~[context-propagation-1.0.2.jar!/:1.0.2]
        at org.springframework.graphql.execution.ContextDataFetcherDecorator.get(ContextDataFetcherDecorator.java:88) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.invokeDataFetcher(ExecutionStrategy.java:309) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.fetchField(ExecutionStrategy.java:286) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.resolveFieldWithInfo(ExecutionStrategy.java:212) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.execution.AsyncExecutionStrategy.execute(AsyncExecutionStrategy.java:55) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.execution.Execution.executeOperation(Execution.java:161) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.execution.Execution.execute(Execution.java:104) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:557) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.GraphQL.lambda$parseValidateAndExecute$11(GraphQL.java:476) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1187) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2309) ~[na:na]
        at graphql.GraphQL.parseValidateAndExecute(GraphQL.java:471) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at graphql.GraphQL.executeAsync(GraphQL.java:439) ~[graphql-java-20.2.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultExecutionGraphQlService.lambda$execute$2(DefaultExecutionGraphQlService.java:82) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4551) ~[reactor-core-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.toFuture(Mono.java:5063) ~[reactor-core-3.5.6.jar!/:3.5.6]
        at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$ReactorRegistrar.lambda$registerAdapters$5(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:244) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapter.fromPublisher(ReactiveAdapter.java:121) ~[spring-core-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.DefaultAsyncServerResponse.create(DefaultAsyncServerResponse.java:186) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse.async(ServerResponse.java:250) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.graphql.server.webmvc.GraphQlHttpHandler.handleRequest(GraphQlHttpHandler.java:111) ~[spring-graphql-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:107) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Trying to replace the `OptionalInt` for an `Optional<Integer>` results in the same error. Furthermore, if I try to invoke the arguments' `isPresent()` method instead of comparing them with `null`, the same error shows up. In fact, comparing them with `null` allows me to make the query without passing any parameters.

Customer type:

```
type Customer {
    dni: ID!
    name: String!
    surname: String!
    accounts: [Account!]!
}
```

Query type:

```
type Query {
    getCustomers(start: Int, end: Int): [Customer!]!
    getCustomer(dni: String!): Customer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what data mapping takes place - be it data from a database, graphql, json deserialization or any transformation of one type of data into another (Java objects are also just a set of bytes), there are always restrictions on the convertibility of types.

Optional or OptionalInt or any other similar wrappers is not supported as you can see in your use case.

To add more, passing optional as method parameter or using these types as class member can be a sign of code smell due to its error prone usage.

Your code example contains exactly what I said: null checks on the Optional params doesn't make this method secure, since wrapper still can be empty, and `getAsInt()` will throw NullPointerException.

Just use regular Integer. Hope it helps